# Непоследовательный вывод символов в консоль

Tags: golang, unicode, ascii

Хотел написать программу генерации паролей для тренировки, при написании допустил ошибку(начиная со 2 ифа я генерил не диапазон и прибавлял начальное значение, а наоборот), и наткнулся на большую неожиданность. Почему-то вывод работает не последовательно. В конце должно выводиться слово `ata` , но оно выводится в центре, а должно быть в конце:

```
6CMW
#1BS&ata"&6,#
```

соответсвие символов кодам смотрю по [таблице](https://www.rapidtables.org/ru/code/text/unicode-characters.html).
Если выводить просто коды, то вывод следующий:

```
25
29
16
54
67
77
31
87
20
12
15
65
37
43
51
34
38
54
17
28
44
35
13
29
30
35
49
66
83
38
30
22
ata
```

Я понял, что 6CWM это коды которые начинаются с 54,67 и далее выводит все видимые символы(до 54 тоже символы не видимы), где-то видимо там же и перенос строки образуется

Максимально упростил код, разбил по отдельным ифам, всё равно `ata` в середине

[сам код чтобы запустить](https://onlinegdb.com/u0cP9AU7k)

сам код чтобы был тут:

```
package main
import ("fmt"
        "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    length := 32
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        var temp int
        var choise int
        choise = rand.Intn(4)
        if  choise == 0{
            temp = rand.Intn(26) + 65 //big symbs
        }
        if  choise == 1{
            temp = rand.Intn(48) + 10 //numbers
        }
        if  choise == 2{
            temp = rand.Intn(97) + 26 //small symbs
        }
        if  choise == 3{
            temp = rand.Intn(33) + 15// cpec symbs
        }
        fmt.Printf("%c",temp)
        // fmt.Println(temp)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%c",'a')
    fmt.Printf("%c",116)
    fmt.Printf("%c",'a')
}
```

Но самый на самый главный вопрос я ответа не нахожу: почему слово `ata` выводится в середине.
В [правильной](https://onlinegdb.com/z4l6WVPcd) версии такого нет

Comment: 13 это код передвижения курсора в начало строки, вон после него всё и печатается с начала строки поверх старых символов

Comment: Ну и 12 переводит курсор на одну строку вниз, да

Comment: @andreymal подскажите пожалуйста какой таблицей вы пользуетесь, я проверил, работает это действительно так, но ни в одной таблице пока не увидел этого, там везде просто пустое место

Comment: Например https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B

Comment: @andreymal  если оформите ответом, приму сразу, спасибо большое